# How do I use the Replace function in VBS

Tags: vbscript

How should I fix this script to find duplicate characters and remove excess?

```
    ColumnValue = ""
    If Len(BaseCell(BaseRowIndex, "SwitchUnit_DD.DD003").Value) >0 Then
    End If

    If Len(BaseCell(BaseRowIndex, "Actuator_DD.DD003").Value) >0 Then
        ColumnValue = ColumnObject.DisplayValue & "-" & BaseCell(BaseRowIndex, "SwitchUnit_DD.DD003").Value & "-" & BaseCell(BaseRowIndex, "Actuator_DD.DD003").Value
    Else
        ColumnValue = ColumnObject.DisplayValue
    End If                      
    Replace(ColumnValue,Find"--",Replacewith"-")
```

Comment: isnt replace syntax REPLACE(OriginalString, FindString, ReplaceWithString) ?

Comment: Replace(ColumnValue,--,-) gives syntax error also.

Comment: `--` and `-` are not strings in VBScript. `"--"` and `"-"` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Replace` is a function, which means that it returns a value. It does not change it. Since you want to change a value, you will have to set the value of the variable, using the function.
The last line should look something like this:

```
ColumnValue = Replace(ColumnValue, "--", "-")
```

Comment: Thank you very much appreciated.